# Automatic keyboard layout on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm using a notebook with external keyboard, both have different layouts. Everytime i use the notebook keyboard, i want to use a specific layout, and the same to the external keyboard.

It's possible?

Comment: What are the 2 layouts you want to use?

Comment: Portuguese ABNT2 on the Notebook and International English on the external keyboard.

Comment: "Portuguese ABNT2" Is that the standard PT layout?

Comment: You may be able to use PowerShell. See [Change Keyboard Input Languages with Powershell](http://drizin.io/Change-Keyboard-Input-Languages-with-Powershell/). Disclaimer: I haven't tried it and I don't know if works with Portuguese ABNT2. Let me know if it works and I will write up an answer.